# In Sublime Text 3 (Macbook Pro), is there a keyboard shortcut for moving cursor forward, outside of auto quote completion without arrow key or mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext, quotes, coding-efficiency

I like the auto quote completion feature, but it's a pain in the neck having to access the arrow keys on my Mac keyboard. Looking for a way to keep my hands in the base typing position to stay productive.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question in Sublime Text forums. I feel silly. To simply type the closing quote at the end of the string has the same functionality as the right arrow key if pressed at the end of the string text and just before the automatic closed quote. Sublime Text will know not to type a second closed quote.